# На сайте после отправки формы открывается модальное окно, как сделать чтоб открывалась страница спасибо

Tags: javascript

Вот код Js он открывает modal_success а нужно страницу спасибо

// FORM SUBMIT
$('.form').on('submit', function(){
var
$form = $(this),
$data = $form.serialize(),
$name = $form.find('input[name="name"]'),
$phone = $form.find('input[name="phone"]'),
$email = $form.find('input[name="email"]'),
$agree = $form.find('input[name="agree"]:checked'),
$rv_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/,
$error = false;

```
    if($form.find('input[name="agree"]').length && !$agree.length){
        $form.find('.form__agree').addClass('invalid');
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $form.find('.form__agree').removeClass('invalid');
    }

    if($name.length){
        if($name.val().length < 3){
            $name.addClass('invalid'); 
            $error = true;
        }else{
            $name.removeClass('invalid');
        }
    }
    if($phone.length){
        if(!$phone.inputmask('isComplete')){
            $phone.addClass('invalid'); 
            $error = true;
        }else{
            $phone.removeClass('invalid');
        }
    }
    if($email.length){
        if($email.val().length < 1 || !$rv_email.test($email.val())){
            $email.addClass('invalid');
            $error = true;      
        }else{
            $email.removeClass('invalid');
        }
    }

    if($error){
        return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "assets/app/send.php", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: $data,
            beforeSend: function($json) {

            },
            success: function($json){
                if($json['success']){

                    $instance = $.fancybox.getInstance();
                    if($instance){$instance.close();}
                    $.fancybox.open({
                        src  : $('#modal_success'),
                        type : 'inline'
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

location.replace(url на вашу страницу)

Подробнее: [Location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

Comment: а куда его здесь вставлять?

Comment: Туда, где у вас в коде открывается(open) модалка))

Answer (score 1):

Если вы говорите о открытии новой страницы, то могу предложить следующее:

```
if($json['success']){
   window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp", "_self");
}
```

В данном случае `open()` откроет в текущем окне страницу https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp